set c++ own comparator function find could not find an already inserted element
I wrote an comparator function for my set which will store an vector of 3 elememts.
Those 3 elements will be sorted always.
Now i insert the 2 elements in the set. But when i try to find the 2nd element, it says could not find. Not able to get the issue in my code.
Can someone help ?
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
using namespace std;
class mycomp
    {
        public:
        bool operator () ( const vector<int>& myvecleft, const vector<int>& myvecright) const
        {
            int x = myvecleft.size();
            for(int i =0; i < x; ++i)
            {
                if(myvecleft[i] < myvecright[i])
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
      
    };
int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    std::set< vector<int>, mycomp> myset;
    vector<int> a1 {-1,-1,2};
    vector<int> a2 {-1,0,1};

    myset.insert(a1);
    myset.insert(a2);
    
    if(myset.find(a2) == myset.end())
     cout<<"\n not found";
    else
     cout<<"\n found";

    return 0;
}


What is myset.size()? (Is this a question of not being able to find an element that exists or of the element not being inserted?)

Perhaps the most common issue with custom comparators is when they do not define a strict weak ordering. Thinking of this, what are the values of mycomp{}::operator()(a1 ,a2) and mycomp{}::operator()(a2 ,a1) (flipping the order of the arguments)? What values do you expect?

while find says that element does not exists, but if i write insert a2 again , size remains 2 only.. so insert is fine behavior. I think find also should have said that element exists.. That's the issue

mycomp{}::operator()(a1 ,a2) and mycomp{}::operator()(a2 ,a1) both are  giving 1

Your mycomp violates the strict weak ordering relation requirements, this results in undefined behavior. mycomp()(a1, a2) returns true, mycomp()(a2, a1) also returns true.

so I think that for strict weak orderding, mycomp(a,b) and mycomp(b,a) should always give difference results ?

@lotusairtel300 "mycomp{}::operator()(a1 ,a2) and mycomp{}::operator()(a2 ,a1) both are giving 1" -- Is this what you expect? Should a1 be ordered before a2 and a2 be ordered before a1?

No, only if one returns true, the other must return false. If the both return false, they are equal. If the both return true, this is undefined behavior.

If you always have 3 elements, why are you using vectors?

You need to add if (myvecright[i] < myvecleft[i]) return false; in the loop so that it doesn't continue to compare unless the compared elements are equal

Same setup, different details: Why does this simple custom-comparator of tuples crash even with strict-weak ordering? Duplicate? Or are the details too different?

Do you even need a custom comparator? What looks like your intended comparator behaviour is the same as the default vector comparator (lexical ordering)

ok, got it, thanks everyone !!
